# Picasso Caching Doesn't Appear to be working

Tags: android, caching, android-fragments, android-activity, picasso

I am using Picasso to handle image loading and caching in my Android Udacity project and I am noticing the caching is not working as I'd expect:

[image]

As you can see on the left fragment, the image has already loaded in an earlier thread. Now, with the same URL link, I am asking Picasso to place that image in the fragment on the right.

Here is the code which generates the grid view on the left fragment (and occurs first):

https://github.com/esend7881/udacity-android-popmovie/blob/a9a1b9a19a37594bb5edd736b7ec59229fb5905a/app/src/main/java/com/ericsender/android_nanodegree/popmovie/adapters/GridViewAdapter.java#L71

```
    String load = String.format(sImgUrl, sImgSize, movie.poster_path);

    Picasso.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
            .load(load)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha)
            .error(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha)
            .resize(550, 775)
            .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

And then here is the code which runs in the right fragment:

https://github.com/esend7881/udacity-android-popmovie/blob/a9a1b9a19a37594bb5edd736b7ec59229fb5905a/app/src/main/java/com/ericsender/android_nanodegree/popmovie/fragments/MovieDetailsFragment.java#L308

```
    Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .load(String.format(sImgUrl, sImgSize, mMovieObj.poster_path))
            .error(R.drawable.blank)
            .fit()// .resize(366, 516)
            .into(mMovieThumb, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Utils.log(sw.toString());
                    Utils.hideViewSafe(mMovieThumbProgress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Utils.log(sw.toString());
                    Utils.hideViewSafe(mMovieThumbProgress);
                }
            });
```

I am using the same application context in each as well as the load text:

`String.format(sImgUrl, sImgSize, mMovieObj.poster_path))`

and

`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

So, I would think Picasso ought to detect when the exact same URL load link appears in the same context within a short period of time from each other and Picasso would then load the exact same image back into the app.

If this is not how Picasso caching works, then how does it?

Comment: Not sure how it works but I guess: size matters. Picasso creating different versions of the same image could explain that behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought Picasso would download the raw image and then do resizing in a subsequent call. If this is in fact what Picasso is doing (only caching the exact size) is there a way to disable that and have Picasso cache the raw image?

Answer (score 1):

As a comment mentioned, I'd guess this is affected by the size of the image being different in both fragments.

I'd recommend using https://github.com/facebook/fresco instead of picasso. It's more efficient, especially with different sizes. You can also directly access cached files if required https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/80

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to the HTTP headers received when getting the image that do not allow caching, as Picasso relies on an HTTP component to do the caching.

Try uploading your image on imgur, try hardcoding that path and see if it works. If that's the case, you'll have to find a workaround on how to get the image from the movie database.